# How can I use multiple prepare statements (mysql, PDO)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Like this my pdo statement is working well:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare("UPDATE animals SET name =? WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();");
$pdo->execute(array($name));
```

If I am using more prepare statements, the UPDATE statement is not working anymore:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO animals (age) values(:age)');
$pdo->execute(array(':age' => $_POST['age'],));

$pdo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO people (name) values(:name)');
$pdo->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name'],));

$pdo = $db->prepare("UPDATE animals SET age =? WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();");
$pdo->execute(array($age));
```

But now my "update" statement is not working anymore.

Comment: How about give different variable names? `$stmt1` `$stmt2`. And `close()` the statments after using it.

Comment: I tried to use the variables $pdo1 and $pdo2, but I get an sql error message `Undefined variable`

Comment: No, sorry I did a mistake, it is working with $pdo1 and $pdo2

Comment: Tried where? Please give full information here, thanks.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Your suggestion just worked fine! Thank you!

Comment: @Jara Last note from me, because you are still stuck: If you are insert into one table something, at this point you have a new `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from that table, but why should this ID also exists in another table at this point? Thing about that! `id=LAST_INSERT_ID();` this is the issue you have. Why should `animals` have IDs that are created just seconds before?!?!? And by the way: Why have animals and people the same name????

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Thank you very much! (I do not think your answer is fraud)  I updated my question to be more clear. I have actually three prepare statement. I just didn't posted the first one, because it didn't have something to do with the problem

Comment: I finally found the answer. Now everything works fine. I would post it but am not allowed to answer my own question here. I do not have to write pdo1, pdo2. I can leave pdo. I only have to change this line `$pdo = $db->prepare("UPDATE animals SET age =? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");` So simple! :)

Comment: this will lead to a data loss. better ask a question how to update your data, explaining what table you want to update with which value and why.

Comment: @YourCommonSense ok, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO people (name) values(:name)');
$stmt1->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name'],));

$stmt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE animals SET name =? WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();");
$stmt2->bindParams(1,$name);
$stmt2->execute();

//did you now that you can do this
//$name='newvalue';
//$stmt2->execute();
//$name='nextvalue';
//$stmt2->execute();
```

Comment: How it's any different from what the OP have?

Comment: For anyone who may be deceived: this answer is a fraud. Juggling with variable names affects nothing.

Comment: @Your Common Sense Look what the OP says in the comment above. :-)

Comment: @Your Common Sense And 2 diff. statments should have to diff. variablenames and it seems that the OP shows not the FULL code.  Fraud, sure, get a live.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Sorry, I was wrong, it is not working..

Comment: @Jarla Sorry im out, POST FULL CODE FULL ERROR MESSAGES and beg for answers. May (at)Your Common Sense has better ideas!